# GridLayoutManager заполнение пространства изображением и отцентровка

Tags: android, xml, recyclerview, material-design

На данный момент для `gridLayoutManager(recycler)` стоят фиксированная высота и ширина изображения внутри ячейки. Изображение всегда квадратное.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы в параметрах указать так, чтобы система заполняла ячейку не оставляя пустых мест, то есть где-то она будет обрезанна. Вторым параметром нужно указать отцентровку, чтобы обрезанные по бокам части не были столь заметны. Поэтому центральная, основная часть будет всегда видна пользователю.

Вот разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/item_user_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:elevation="2dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_img"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:src="@drawable/default_avatar" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/user_img">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/search_btn_like"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/cards_heart_red" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/search_btn_chat"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/message" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/item_user_top_relative"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="0.8"
            android:background="@android:color/white">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/user_name"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/user_age"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/user_country"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```